# ExtJS and autoloading URL

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

I am using a php framework which requires an index.php file to be used (can be removed with .htaccess, but I would prefer not to do so in my current situation). the problem is that in some cases ExtJS is autoloading classes at URL's like the following

```
mysite.com/index.php/path/to/file.js
```

Is there a way to set the URL in which the ExtJS classes will be loaded from?

Comment: depending on your php framework, there should be a function that will build a URL to your site. you can then append the rest of the path to that root. Example, $getRootUrl(). '/path/to/file.js'. You can then build an absolute reference instead of a relative one.

Comment: The framework is Kohana. Do you mean an absolute path for extjs or my regular urls?

Comment: i usually build absolute paths for javascript / css /images. It helps to separate out your content of your site from the MVC stuff. When the content is referenced relatively within you page and you want to change your controller name or use the same view in multiple actions all of those links break. Its much easier to make a content folder on your site to place all images/ js/ css in to reference absolutely and build the links with the php framework.

Comment: Here you go.....http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/URL#base

Comment: The problem is with the ExtJS auto-loading. So my include of the original ext-all.js, css etc are all fine, but when I have navigated to pages where the url has the index.php, extjs is autoloading with the index.php included in the url

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using app.js and loader then you need to set 2 things:
appFolder property on your Ext.application config
and the path config on the Loader for any other components outside your app structure.

Like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name:'MyApp',
    appFolder:'js/MyApp/app'
```

and

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled:true,
  paths: {
      'Ext.ux': 'js/extjs/ux'
  }
```